# Xamarin Android Bottom tab bar title word cutting

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tabs

I have a page with bottom tab bar, When I select a long title , the title is cutting at the end. How to prevent this, I tried with reducing the size, but in that case the title is become too small.How to add a trail truncation to this .

Comment: Are you using Shell or Tabbed page, could you add your xaml code there?

Comment: @Shaw Tabbed Page

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabbedPage [custom render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) to make multiline title for TabbedPage in Android.

Firstly, create MyTabbedPageRenderer in Adroid project, get TextView that display TabbedPage title bar, then set multiline `smallTextView.SetLines(2)`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace gensture.Droid
{
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage tabbedPage;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
     
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            tabbedPage = e.NewElement as TabbedPage;
            bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;              
            ChangeFont();
        }

    }
    void ChangeFont()
    {
        
        var bottomNavMenuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;

        for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavMenuView.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var item = bottomNavMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
            var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);

            var smallTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0));
            var largeTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1));
            smallTextView.SetLines(2);
            largeTextView.SetLines(2);

          
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then display TabbedPage.

```
<TabbedPage
x:Class="gensture.TabbedPage1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#999999"
android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Black"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
<!--  Pages can be added as references or inline  -->
<ContentPage Title="Tab 1" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab22222222222222222222" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 4" />
```

The screenshot:

[image]